# Wild ricochet and clan defiance?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Suppose I cast a [Wild Ricochet](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wild%20Ricochet) onto a [Clan Defiance](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Clan%20Defiance). My Clan Defiance targets flying, non flying and player: can I redirect all of them?

If I do, can I choose the target to be all on the player or do the new targets have to be under same targeting rules?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, and no.

- The choice of mode ("Choose one or more") cannot be changed.<sup>[CR 114.7]</sup>
- The number of targets cannot be changed.<sup>[CR 114.6a]</sup>
- Any number of the targets can be changed (including zero).<sup>[CR 114.6c]</sup>
- The targeting conditions still apply.

For example, if the original spell targeted a flying creature and a player, the copy must also target a flying creature and a player.

Or in the example you gave, the copy will also have to target a flying creature, a non-flying creature and a player.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can redirect all those targets. Wild Ricochet says "choose new targets" (plural), not "choose a new target" (singular).

No, you can't choose to target a player with all three effects. You still have to follow the targeting rules on the card, the same way the original caster had to - Wild Ricochet doesn't make you exempt to them.

Comment: So the choose new targets has to follow the cards requirements... Is there a green or red card that deals x dammage to how many targets or players you want so I could abuse wild ricochet

Comment: That wouldn't work either. Damage division is done at casting time, and you can't have a single instance of the word "target" target the same object twice. e.g. If the original did 2 to creature A, 1 to creature B and 1 to opponent, you could do at most 3 damage to the opponent.